# Creating a Sharepoint Message pop from a sharepoint list - internal messaging

Tags: 2007, sharepoint-designer

I'm after a internal messaging in Sharepoint.
Something that a user can type some comments and it appears to other users including there usernames.Not neccesarily directing it to a specific users.
Anybody  came across this or created something similar.
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the following resources. You can make it work with minimum alteration

- [Using Jquery In Sharepoint To Display Notifications For Open Tasks](http://weblogs.asp.net/jan/archive/2009/05/07/using-jquery-in-sharepoint-to-display-notifications-for-open-tasks.aspx)
- [SharePoint Tasks Popup using JavaScript API](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/sharepoint/SharePointTasksPopup.aspx)
- [jQuery Ticker for SharePoint Announcement List](http://littletalk.wordpress.com/2009/07/23/jquery-ticker-for-sharepoint-announcement-list/)